# Oblivion TES Construction Set - Self-made landscape patch not working

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion, the-elder-scrolls-construction-set

**Introduction:** I made a very small landscape patch mod to make two different mods compatible.

---

**The Mods:**

[Order of the Dragon EV](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/45258)

[Fall of the Ayleids](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/44474)

**The compatibility problem:**

The landscape changes made by OotD made it so that the large Ayleid tower was unreachable, as it was floating high in the air, which is very bad for immersion, and quest-breaking.

Now using The Elder Scrolls Construction Set, I moved the tower (and other floating things around it) to the ground and it was looking fine in the mod creator.

---

**Now the problem:**

After saving my work as a new mod, I added it to the Data folder, I activated it and made sure to place it after all other mods. As I used Wrye Bash, I placed it before the bashed patch at first, rebuild the bashed patch, and started the game.
The game started fine and everything was normal, but when I came to the place that I had altered in the mod creator nothing had changed, and the tower was still floating in the air.
After this I quit the game, made a new safe file, and checked again, but nothing had changed.
Then I moved the mod after the bashed patch, rebuilt the patch, tested again, and it did not work.

**Final:** 

That is it, I have been looking online for good tutorials and people with the same problem, but I can't find anything helpful. If anyone has some good tutorials please post it in a comment, and of course if you have a solution please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, I have found a partial solution and an alternative workaround. It is not a perfect solution, but it does its job.

**Partial solution:** First for the partial solution I used [this guide](https://cs.elderscrolls.com/index.php?title=De-Isolation_Tutorial),
but this was only a partial solution as it only seemed to fix some problems with the landscape, but was not able move the watchtower of the "Fall of the Ayleids" mod.

**Alternative workaround:** For the alternative workaround I edited the mods individually, this worked, but it is just a workaround. The problem with this workaround is that if I were ever to reinstall the mod, or a new version of the mod were to come out, I would not be able to just apply the previously made patch, but would have to do it again.

For information on editing mods you can take a look at the [BethesdaGameStudios Creation Kit tutorial playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLL9MQHsCibbY1veZLmPEKxyUfeSUEw3EG), because, even if this is for Skyrim, it seems the basic functions of the Creation Kit have not changed so much from the previous version.